# jQuery Accordion - Conflict with other jQuery items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, hoverintent, jquery

Well I'm using multiple jQuery sliders on this same page & somehow I have managed to make it work, but now there's another problem:

http://www.tradeglobus.com/index2.php

The accordion menu : http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent

in "Premium Memberships" div actually works on mouse hoverintent, when I added "jquery noConflict" then everything else started to work but the accordion menu is now working on CLICK event only, not on hover.

Here's the Code:

```
  <script>
  var $accui = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  $(function() {
$accui( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    event: "click hoverintent"
});
  });

  var cfg = ($.hoverintent = {
sensitivity: 7,
interval: 50
  });

  $.event.special.hoverintent = {
setup: function() {
    $( this ).bind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
},
teardown: function() {
    $( this ).unbind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
},
handler: function( event ) {
    var that = this,
        args = arguments,
        target = $( event.target ),
        cX, cY, pX, pY;

    function track( event ) {
        cX = event.pageX;
        cY = event.pageY;
    };
    pX = event.pageX;
    pY = event.pageY;
    function clear() {
        target
            .unbind( "mousemove", track )
            .unbind( "mouseout", arguments.callee );
        clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function handler() {
        if ( ( Math.abs( pX - cX ) + Math.abs( pY - cY ) ) < cfg.sensitivity ) {
            clear();
            event.type = "hoverintent";
            event.originalEvent = {};
            jQuery.event.handle.apply( that, args );
        } else {
            pX = cX;
            pY = cY;
            timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
        }
    }
    var timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
    target.mousemove( track ).mouseout( clear );
    return true;
}
};
</script>
```

Can anyone of you PLEASE highlight any mistakes in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems like to be correct.
I see that your web site using jquery version: v1.6.2, 
in this forum i find that some versions have the same problem:

[jquery special event hoverintent on accordion not working in jquery 1.7](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-special-event-hoverintent-on-accordion-not-working-in-jquery-1-7)

Try to upgrade your jQuery...maybe it will work.

Comment: but I'm using the latest versions of both jquery & jqueryui:

ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js

it was working perfectly until I added $accui = jQuery.noConflict(true);

Then all other jQuery sliders & ticker started to work properly, but its now not working on hover but on click.